# Need my iPhone app to allow users to write google reviews

Tags: iphone, ios5, google-plus

I'm building an iPhone application.
One of the requirements is that it needs to alloe users to write a review in google plus local website.

In Android, I can do this by opening google maps application and write it from there, but iPhone's google maps application doesn't let me write reviews.

I've been researching a lot and the only way I found to write reviews from an iPhone device is by using Google+ Local application.

Is there any way of opening this application from my own application and send some kind of parameter to a specific Google+ Local page?

Or is it any other way to write a review?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same functionality in an iOS app for iPad... either hybrid or native... that could send reviews to G+ as well. Hybrid would be ideal so that the web scripting could be easily be repurposed for Android or iOS...

But as far as I know, Google does not provide write functionality with their API.